# How to fix docker command prompt

Tags: shell, docker

When I start `emacs -q` and run `M-x shell` there is formatting error when connecting to docker container as follows,

```
$ docker container exec -it b3c85fd9c5eaa2e64fc5aac9025d1f9c3b3fe47ca39008f40ddd436338d755f5 bash
]0;root@b3c85fd9c5ea: /root@b3c85fd9c5ea:/# ls
ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
]0;root@b3c85fd9c5ea: /root@b3c85fd9c5ea:/#
```

Here is its screenshot

[image]

Comment: What's the value of the `PS1` environment variable in that container?

Comment: I can recommend https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm and https://github.com/Silex/docker.el for docker.

Comment: @wasamasa here is `echo $PS1` output `\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value of `PS1` contains ANSI escape codes that can only be processed correctly by a terminal emulator (like the built-in term.el or vterm), not by `M-x shell` or `M-x eshell`.  Set it to something simpler like `\u@\h:\w\$`, this could be done with the `-e` switch for the `docker-container-exec` command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cd` instead of `docker attach`.
So, at the eshell prompt, instead of attaching to a running container with

```
$ docker attach  <container_id>
```

cd into it with

```
$ cd /docker:<container_id>:/
```

You'll get the full eshell experience with this method.